# UIPageViewController load ChildViews multiple times

Tags: swift

I've subclassed UIPageViewController, and it works fine. Except the fact that going back and forth load new instances of the pages, instead of (as i would expect) retrieving the instance it loaded previously.
Aren't the references supposed to be strong?

Following is my code.

Thank you for your help.

Pierrick

```
class CustomPageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

var view1: FirstCustomViewController!
var view2: SecondCustomViewController!
var view3: ThirdCustomViewController!
var views = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.dataSource = self;

    self.view1 = FirstViewController()
    self.view2 = SecondViewController()
    self.view3 = ThirdViewController()

    self.views = [self.view1, self.view2, self.view3]
    self.setViewControllers([self.view1], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

// MARK: - PageViewControllerDataSource

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    let index = self.views.indexOfObject(viewController)

    if (index > 0) {
        return self.views.objectAtIndex(index-1) as? UIViewController
    }

    return nil
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    let index = self.views.indexOfObject(viewController)

    if (index < self.views.count-1) {
        return self.views.objectAtIndex(index+1) as? UIViewController
    }

    return nil
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the faulty function is in FirstViewController, SecondViewController, ThirdViewController. When i wrote my question, the view controller loaded the view following the method "viewWillAppear".
As soon as i moved the code to "viewDidLoad", the views stopped to load multiple times.